# Page Wise totals on last page in RDLC reprot

Tags: report, rdlc

I am using rdlc reprot in VB (Visual Studio) with MS Sql Express. I want the output as given below :

```
SrNo.      Amount
1          100
2          100
3          100
4          100
Group Total = 400
5          200
6          200
Page1 Total = 800
***************************PAGE1 END HERE****************
7.         200
8.         200
9          200
Group2 Total=1000
Page2 Total = 600
****************************PAGE 2 END HERE*****************

Page1 Total = 800
Page 2 Total =600

Grand Total = 1400
******************************LAST PAGE END HERE**************
```

I am able to get all output except Page1 Total and Page2 Total on last page.

For Group Total I have used Sum function of rdlc with Table1_Group2 Scope.

For Grand Total I have used Sum function of rdlc with dataset scope.

For Page Wise total on each page I have used Reprot footer text box with code `=Sum(ReportItems!amt.Value)`.

How to get each page wise total on last page again?

Answer (score 0):

you can use vb code in Code tab.
add Shared List property and method accept 2 parameter
1- page total
2- page number (use this method "Globals!PageNumber.ToString()")
add textbox in footer and in expression call this method
in the last page ("Globals!PageNumber.ToString() = Globals!TotalPages.ToString()")
use Shared property

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on my environment, the steps below are for you reference.

1-Open the report code window by clicking Report Menu-->Report Properties, and the click on the code tab

2-Add the below code in the code-window

```
Public Shared PageTotal As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)
Public Shared Function Total(ByVal Item As Integer, byval Amount As Decimal) As Decimal
If PageTotal Is Nothing Then
PageTotal = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)
End If
If Not PageTotal.ContainsKey(Item) Then
PageTotal.Add(Item, Amount)
End If
Return Amount
End Function
Public Shared Function GetTotal(ByVal Item As Integer) As String
if Item=1 then return ""
Return PageTotal(Item-1).ToString()
End Function
```

3-On the report footer, replace your present expression with the below
    =Code.Total(Globals!PageNumber,Sum(Reportitems!Credit.Value))

4-On the page header, add a text box and enter below expression
    =Code.GetTotal(Globals!PageNumber)

Run Project

****NOTE
Set display mode befor View report

reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);